# CouchDb fetch all documents where ID starts with prefix

Tags: couchdb

I want to fetch all documents in a CouchDB database where the document ID starts with a given prefix.

Did some searching and found, according to the [CouchDB Documentation](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/ddocs/views/collation.html#string-ranges), the best way to accomplish this is by using a `startkey` and `endkey`, where the `startkey` is the prefix, and the `endkey` is the prefix with a high-value unicode character appended at the end.

So, as I understand it, a call to `"http://server:5984/some_db/_all_docs?startkey=2018&endkey=2018\ufff0&include_docs=true"` should fetch all docs from `some_db` with an ID starting with '2018'.

That url is being encoded by the web browser as follows:
`http://server:5984/some_db/_all_docs?startkey=2018&endkey=2018%EF%BF%B0&include_docs=true`

And the response I get back is `{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid UTF-8 JSON"}`

So I tried just sticking to pure ASCII and used `~` instead of `\ufff0`. Same response. Also got the same response using a `z`.

If I do something like `_all_docs?startkey=2018&endkey=2019&include_docs=true&inclusive_end=false` everything works fine and I get the expected results. However, I can't guarantee the prefix will always be a number, and I get the impression trying to implement it like that programmatically will cause me issues some where or some how. Any thoughts?

I'm using Dart running in the web browser to make the request, if it makes a difference.

#### Update

So, I've realized in actuality `_all_docs` does not support the `endkey` and `startkey` parameters. The request I originally thought was working was actually just returning the entire database.

I had assumed `_all_docs` supports startkey and andkey because I have used PouchDB in the past, [which does](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#batch_fetch) support those parameters in the `allDocs()` function.

Still looking for a solution, since this project is *not* using PouchDB, but at least now I know what the problem is.

#### Update 2

Previous update was wrong, Although the documentation of `_all_docs` doesn't have these parameters listed, there is a note which I had missed indicating it also supports the [parameters for view](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/ddoc/views.html#api-ddoc-view), see my answer below.

Comment: Why do you think `_all_docs` doesn't support `endkey` and `startkey`?

Comment: I had though that because it's not one of the listed parameters under the [documentation](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/bulk-api.html#db-all-docs) and because using it wasn't working. Thus I thought those parameters weren't supported. I didn't notice the part which said it also had all the same parameters as a view. As stated in my answer below, I eventually did figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I figured it out.

I was wrong in my update, `startkey` and `endkey` *are* supported by `_all_docs` because it's just a built-in view, so all the parameters for views apply. However, it expects the passed values to be JSON values, not just a bare string as a key. The solution is just to put quotation marks around the keys.

That is, encoded quotation marks, e.g. `startkey=%222018%22&endkey=%222018%EF%BF%B0%22`